# Filter enum in Silverlight ComboBox

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, combobox, enums

I have an enum representing possible configurations. (the following is just an example...)

```
public enum ConfigurationType {
    [Description("Minimal Configuration")]
    Minimal = 0,
    [Description("Standard Configuration")]
    Standard,
    [Description("Premium Configuration")]
    Premium
}
```

Right now I am binding a property of type `ConfigurationType` in my class to a ComboBox using a value converter (found [here](http://charlass.wordpress.com/2009/07/29/binding-enums-to-a-combobbox-in-silverlight/)) to display the Description. That works fine. What I would like to do however, is be able to disable the selection of specific enum members on the fly, the result being they would not show up in the ComboBox.

I have tried converting this enum to be a flags enum and then binding to a set of the flags, but didn't get very far. Any pointers on that or other suggestions?

**Edit - flags example**

When trying to use flags, I changed the enum to:

```
[Flags]
public enum ConfigurationType {
    [Description("Minimal Configuration")]
    Minimal = 1 << 0,
    [Description("Standard Configuration")]
    Standard = 1 << 1,
    [Description("Premium Configuration")]
    Premium = 1 << 2
}

public ConfigurationType AvailableConfigs = ConfigurationType.Standard | ConfigurationType.Premium;
```

It actually works for being able to assign bitwise-or'd list of these to a variable such as AvailableConfigs (as shown above), but then the value converter part was the hang-up. I wasn't sure how to implement a value converter to get the description of each flag present in AvailableConfigs, and be able to convert back to a variable (also of ConfigurationType) such as SelectedConfiguration. The setter of SelectedConfiguration would of course enforce only one flag at a time being present.

Comment: That example you are following is only good for the simple "list every enum" case as it returns a complete list of all enums for a given type. You would want to ignore the caching code and filter the enums you want on the fly via reflection. I will add an example...

Comment: @HiTechMagic I'm a newbie with reflection, are you talking about the portion of the code in that converter I linked that actually grabs the description from the properties? Also, is the converterparameter passed in the xaml, and what exactly should be passed?

Comment: @HiTechMagic thank you so much, I anxiously await your answer :)

Comment: Forgot you can't bind a ConverterParameter so this needs a slightly different approach. What drives your AvailableConfig setting? Is it static (e.g. can be defined in the XAML) or is it dynamic (driven by app changes)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can define the available options in XAML, you could do this:

### in your EnumValuesConverter.cs

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (value == null)
        return null;
    else
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)parameter))
        {
            return EnumValueCache.GetValues(value.GetType());
        }
        return EnumValueCache.GetValues(value.GetType()).Where(x => parameter.ToString().Contains(x.ToString()));
    }
}
```

And bind with a ConverterParameter used like this:

```
<ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,27,0,0" Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding MyEnumProperty, Converter={StaticResource enumConverter}, ConverterParameter=Minimal-Standard}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding MyEnumProperty, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Which will show only the `Minimal` and `Standard` options using the ConverterParameter as a simple string filter.

If you need something more dynamic just say so. You can't bind ConverterParameters (unfortunately) so it will need more work.

### Dynamic property solution

To do the same thing using an `AvailableConfigs` property, you would need to implement a MultiBinding solution (which allows you to bind to multiple properties).

The order of the bindings is important as that will be the order they are passed to the converter.

### e.g.

```
<ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,27,0,0" Name="comboBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" >
    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource enumConverter}">
            <Binding Path="MyEnumProperty" />
            <Binding Path="AvailableConfigs" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
</ComboBox>
```

**MultiBinding is only part of WPF and not Silverlight so here are a few Silverlight MultiBinding solutions:**

- http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/05/silverlight-multibinding-solution-for-silverlight-4/
- http://www.olsonsoft.com/blogs/stefanolson/post/Improvements-to-Silverlight-Multi-binding-support.aspx

Comment: Many thanks to you. The available choices are driven by events within the application. If I had a dollar for every time I needed something in Silverlight that is only available in WPF... anyways, I will look into the MultiBinding options. I might just have to look into a way to move it to the XML instead. Again, thanks for your efforts. You win.